# SQL server job owner account password change impact

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-job

I have around 20 jobs running in SQL Server 2008. The owner of this account is Domain\Administrator. Now there is need for changing password for administrator. I'm just wondering if this change will have any impact on jobs.
Please help me clarify the doubt.

Comment: you run sql agent jobs as  Domain\Administrator?  You have a bigger problem than the one you asked!

Comment: @MitchWheat can you please let me know what is the problem? and solution is most welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time the password for a service account changes, any services configured to run under that account will need their credentials updated (new password entered). This is true for windows services, SQL agent proxy credentials, IIS app pools, anything. Without this the service will not startup next time it stops/recycles, and will cease to be able to access external resources that require the service to authenticate.

If instead you use the Network Service account, you never need worry about this. Of course, this is only applicable in cases where the identity of an individual application on a server is synonymous with the application itself (eg: if your app is the only thing running on a specific server there really is no downside).

It's fairly unusual to run jobs under a domain administrator account, whether via SQL agent proxy or (worse) just running SQL agent itself as doman admin. If you *really need* those credentials for specific jobs, at least use a SQL agent proxy for just those jobs, and preferably one with only the permissions you require.

Running as domain admin is a security disaster waiting to happen (unless you're in a dev/resource domain, in which case it's still questionable at best, shear lazyness otherwise).